# How safe it is to install tlp

Tags: 14.04, asus, overheating, tlp

I have been using ubuntu for a while now. I just got a new asus laptop, and did install ubuntu 14.04 in a dual booting on it. I tend to use ubuntu than windows. But when in ubuntu it seems to hit a little bit more.

I have research and almost off blogs about things to install after ubuntu seem to promote the tlp tool. with ppa `add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp`.

I am wondering about how this can positively and negatively affect the laptop, in terms to performance, speed of the hard drive (7200) etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing [thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) with `sudo apt-get install thermald` which is ubuntu made and a feature for 14.04. I noticed some better control of the cpu fan on my asus laptop. Seems to work but it's a daemon (runs in background) so I have no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did install it but frankly I am not sure I see the difference. Other places they suggest installation of intel_pstate on top of it.

Comment: I just installed intel_pstate. I'll let you know if I notice any change!